# Spec for File creation and writing into File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

I am new here. I am working on a project with some tests. I have some problems with writing spec for a class. I am done with some simple specs but I have no clue how to write for this one. Any help will be highly appreciated.

My class

```
Class Writer

def initialize(filepath)
  @filepath = RAILS_ROOT + filepath
  @xml_document = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
end

def open
  File.open(@filepath,"w") do |f|
    @gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(f)
    @gz.write(%[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n])
    @gz.write(%[<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n])
    yield self
    @gz.write(%[</urlset>])
    @gz.close
  end
end

def write_entry_to_xml(entry)
   node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( "url" , @xml_document )
   node["loc"] = entry.loc
   node["changefreq"] = entry.changfreq
   node["priority"] = entry.priority
   node["lastmod"] = entry.lastmod
   @gz.write(node.to_xml)
end

end
```

What I have written so far is as follows

```
describe "writer" do 
 before :each do 
  @time = Time.now
  @filepath = RAILS_ROOT + "/public/sitemap/test/sitemap_test.xml.gz"
  File.open(@filepath,"w") do |f|
   @gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(f)
  end
  @xml_document = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
  @entry = Sitemap::Entry.new("location", "monthly", "0.8", @time)
end 

describe "open" do 
 it "should create a file and write xml entries to it" do 
 end
end

describe "write_entry_to_xml" do 
 it "should format and entry to xml node and write it" do 
  node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( "url" , @xml_document )
  node["loc"].should == @entry.loc
  node["changefreq"].should == @entry.changfreq
  node["priority"].should == @entry.priority
  node["lastmod"].shoul == @entry.lastmod
end
```

end

Can anyone help me in writing the complete specs for this class.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you not copy/paste code? `Class`, `shoul`?

Comment: what do you mean by copy/paste the code? Do you mean the class code and spec code is same?

Comment: testing means testing your actual code, not a copy of the contents of your real code. you should learn about test doubles to know how to test particular statements of your real code

Comment: can u please guide me for this specific class

Comment: @farnoy Can you please help me in this problem?

Comment: Trust me, there's no way you can understand testing simply by one example. I recommend you read a book about the concept of testing and test doubles. Then, look at open source projects on github and analyze code and tests. I'm not recommending rails for that though, they have a pretty complicated test setup and it's not valuable for begginers. Try to analyze simple gems and small libraries

Comment: @farnoy Actually I need to do it by today in my semester project and I dont have too much time to read a book now. I have a book about rspec which i will study but for now I need to complete my task. If you could help it will be a life saver and I will be highly thankful

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe it will hurt you more than it will help. Also, what's the point of giving off some kind of school project with code that you won't understand or be able to explain and most importantly: do again without anyone's help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to do all this for you, but here are examples of how I am testing my code:

- [actual code](https://github.com/farnoy/ropet/blob/master/lib/ropet/parser.rb)
- [it's spec](https://github.com/farnoy/ropet/blob/master/spec/parser_spec.rb)

Notice this: `Ropet::Config.expects(:new).returns(config)`, this can be used for your `Nokogiri::XML::Node#new`.

My specs use RSpec and Mocha, I like the simplicity of this setup and what can be done with those simple tools.

#### Edit: rough spec for

```
def write_entry_to_xml(entry)
   node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( "url" , @xml_document )
   node["loc"] = entry.loc
   node["changefreq"] = entry.changfreq
   node["priority"] = entry.priority
   node["lastmod"] = entry.lastmod
   @gz.write(node.to_xml)
end
```

It could be something like this, though i don't know the purpose of your code.

```
it 'writes entry to xml' do
    content = double('output')
    node = double('node'); node.should_receive(:to_xml).and_return(content);
    gz = double('gz'); gz.should_receive(:write).with(content)
    w = Writer.new("some_path"); w.open
    w.instance_variable_set(:@gz, gz) # i'm guessing @gz is assigned after open only?
    entry = # i don't know what entry is
    Nokogiri::XML::Node.stub(:new).and_return(node)
    node.should_receive(:[]).with("loc", entry.loc)
    node.should_receive(:[]).with("changefreq", entry.changefreq)
    node.should_receive(:[]).with("priority", entry.priority)
    node.should_receive(:[]).with("lastmod", entry.lastmod)
    w.write_entry_to_xml(entry)
end
```

Comment: Can you give me a start by providing some rough sketch of specs for this class ?

Comment: ok, i've done that, but i don't know if it's accurate for your case since i don't know what it does